# Pandas: Sliding window, summing app 14 day data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sliding-window

I do wonder how it is possible to make sliding windows in Pandas.
I have a dataframe with three columns.

```
Country | Number | DayOfTheYear
===================================
No      | 50     | 0
No      | 20     | 1
No      | 37     | 2
```

I would love to see 14 day chunks for every country and day combination.
The country think can be ignored for the moment, since I can filter those manually in some way. But imagine there is only one country, is there a smart way to get some sort of summed up sliding window, resulting in something like the following?

```
Country | Sum | DatesOftheYear
===================================
No      | 504     | 0-13
No      | 207     | 1-14
No      | 337     | 2-15
```

I would also accept if if they where disjunct, being only 0-13, 14-27, etc.
But I just cannot come along with Pandas. I know an old SQL solution, but is there anybody having a nice idea for Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a rolling windows of your dataframe, you can simply use the `.rolling` function of pandas : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html

In your case : `df["Number"].rolling(14).sum()`

Comment: I see, it actually works. The only thing which seems weird is how it summed up the dayOfTheYearThings as well. I mean, the numbers are correct, but those columns are looking quite weird. Is there a clever way to let them stay as they are, not being summed up?

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand your question, but the rolling function will only work for your number column in the way you expect. To create the `DatesOftheYear` column you can for example do the following: `df["Days"].shift(13).astype(str) + "-" + df["Days"].astype(str)`

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I just found out that I did a mistake in using the command. It works totally fine now :)